# hide bootstrap divs one by one when geeting a particular resolution(responsive)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

`parentRow` is a row containing 3 or more divs. It should not go to second row. The first div "Apple" should be visible in every resolution. The second div "Orange" should be visible for `col-md-4` and `col-lg-4` and `col-xl-4` while 3rd div "Pineapple" should be visible only for `col-lg-4` and `col-xl-4`?

In short there is a row containing 3 or more divs (Bootstrap 4.3.1 grids) when the screen is resized the divs should hide one by one and at smaller resolution one div(grid) should remain visible?

Shorter and effective method is welcomed. Please avoid media queries.

```html
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 parentRow">
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        Apple 
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        Orange
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        Pineapple
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) to hide elements on certain breakpoints.

For example `.d-none.d-md-block` will be hidden on `xs` and `sm` resolutions, and will have `display: block` on `md`, `lg` and `xl`.

```css
.box {
  padding: .75rem;
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col box">
    apple (always visible)
  </div>
  <div class="col box d-none d-md-block">
    Orange (visible on md and bigger)
  </div>
  <div class="col box d-none d-lg-block">
    PineApple (visible on lg and bigger)
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code you can put on any page for a quick reference when you do a lot of resizing tests.

It show just the div with the name = active size of the screen and make the rest hidden:

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="d-none d-xl-block          ">XL</div>
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">LG</div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">MD</div>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">SM</div>
    <div class="       d-xs-block d-sm-none">XS</div>
  </body>
```